# TypeError: must be str, not NoneType in bluetooth

Tags: python, typeerror, non-type

`

```
def arduino_connect():
    global sock
    print("Cihazlar axtarılır....")
    nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
    num = 0
    for i in nearby_devices:
        num+=1
        print(str(num)+":"+bluetooth.lookup_name(i)+" MAC: "+i)
        if i=="00:21:13:00:EF:19":
            selection = num-1
    bd_addr = nearby_devices[selection]
    port = 1
    print("Sən seçdin:" +bluetooth.lookup_name(bd_addr))
    sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
    sock.connect((bd_addr,port))
```

`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ordubot.py", line 92, in <module>
    test(wake)
  File "ordubot.py", line 81, in test
    response(voice)
  File "ordubot.py", line 57, in response
    arduino_connect()
  File "ordubot.py", line 38, in arduino_connect
    print(str(num)+":"+bluetooth.lookup_name(i)+" MAC: "+i)
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

This code gives this error, can you please help?

In this code, I want python to connect to the mac address specified by bluetooth, but this code gives an error.

Comment: `bluetooth.lookup_name(i)` either has no data or is returning None type for some "i". Please check your stdout console as you are printing this to know which data point caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

When joining items using the `+` operator, they have to be of the same type.
That means that if `bluetooth.lookup_name(i)` returns a result which isn't a string (a `NoneType` in your case) than the concatenation fails.

You can use format string to print the result anyway -

```
print(f"{}:{} MAC: {}".format(num, bluetooth.lookup_name(i), i)
```

This will work even if not all of the arguments of `format` are strings.